# Can you read text from a PDF with lua in corona sdk

Tags: sdk, lua, corona

I want to take an email with an attachment and read the PDF-file in order to retrieve certain data.

The data is located at the same place in each document (header and footer)

Does LUA have any modules for reading PDF-files that would do the trick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up switching to Python to do this, because Python has plenty of modules supporting what I was trying to achieve.

I never found a suitable solution with LUA.